# JDialog opening very slow

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm having some problems while working on a project for school. The JDialog renders very slow. Let me show you.

This is the GUI:

[image: GUI]

When I click "Advance time" it takes around 3 seconds to open the JDialog. When it's open I get this (which is fine):

[image: Save screen]

But when I drag that JDialog around, I get this (which is not ok):

[image: Slow]

It also takes very long to close the JDialog. It closes, but you can still see it:

[image: close]

This is the snippet of code where I think the problem lays, it's the code for the menu-bar:

```
private JMenu editMenu()
{
    JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
    editMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);

    JMenuItem advanceTimeMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Advance time");
    advanceTimeMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    advanceTimeMenuItem.setToolTipText("Advance the internal clock");
    advanceTimeMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
        {
            //We first create panel to add to the dialog.
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            //Calendar
            AdvanceTimePanel calendar = new AdvanceTimePanel(internalClockController);

            //Button that will be used to confirm the system time change.
            JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
            //Add actionlistener to the save button
            btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    Date selectedDate = calendar.getDate();
                    try
                    {                           
                        internalClockController.updateDateTime(selectedDate);                           
                    } catch (InvalidInternalClockException e1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("InvalidInternalClockException: " + e1.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
            //Add the components to the panel.
            panel.add(btnSave);
            //This is the calendar added to the panel.
            panel.add(calendar);
            //Create the dialog and add the panel to it.
            JDialog jDialog = new JDialog();
            jDialog.add(panel);
            jDialog.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 200);
            jDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            jDialog.setVisible(true);
        }


    });

    editMenu.add(advanceTimeMenuItem);
```

Does someone have an idea how to speed things up?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Improve the speed of AdvanceTimePanel calendar = new AdvanceTimePanel(internalClockController);. What happens if you replace the panel with a simple JLabel? Is it opened fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are handled on one single thread. (Also repaint events.) For the application to remain
responsive, perform longer actions a bit later by using `invokeLater`, as below:

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ... // All code here
            }
        });
    }
```

This is quite wordy; Java 8 allows:

```
advanceTimeMenuItem.addActionListener(
        (event) -> {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(
                () -> {
                    ... // All code
                });
        });
```

Comment: I have tried it and when I click on "Advance time" it definitely feels smoother, thank you for that. But the other problems still remain.

Comment: There are two `actionPerformed`s - so twice to modify?